# How to get error details from UpdateListItems SOAP response?

Tags: sharepoint, soap

I'm writting an iOS-client for Microsoft SharePoint. My goal is to update a datetime field of a list item and get details on errors. I have a datetime field with custom server-side validation.

Here is a request to /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>{405FFE91-946E-4B2F-861E-DDB24F1629F2}</listName>
      <updates>
        <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
          <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
            <Field Name="ID">1</Field>
            <Field Name="DateTime_x0020_E">2000-08-08 07:00:00 +0000</Field>
          </Method>
        </Batch>
      </updates>
    </UpdateListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is a response:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <UpdateListItemsResponse 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <UpdateListItemsResult>
                <Results>
                    <Result ID="1,Update">
                        <ErrorCode>0x8102001c</ErrorCode>
                        <ErrorText>Invalid date/time value.

A date/time field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.</ErrorText>
                        <z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x0100D3AA6E2413CF1645A9101D3421B797AE" ows_Title="test of time" ows_DateTi... skipped...
```

This response doesn't say anything about valid range of this field. However, when I try to set invalid date at SharePoint site, I get proper error:

[image: SharePoint provides details on error]

**Q:** how to get details on error using SharePoint SOAP service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out where is my mistake. The field is date-only, so probably SharePoint doesn't accept value as `2000-08-08 07:00:00 +0000`. When I send date only:

```
<Field Name="DateTime_x0020_E">1995-08-08</Field>
```

I get the proper error text:

```
<Result ID="1,Update">
   <ErrorCode>0x810200c5</ErrorCode>
   <ErrorText>[DateTime E] - [Date should be after July 1, 2007]</ErrorText>
   ...
</Result>
```